# localhost has acquired a second IP address?

Tags: linux, networking, router, dns

A strange problem occurred today. After installing updates and rebooting my archlinux system I noticed that postfix had not restarted. It was reporting an error:

```
postfix: fatal: parameter inet_interfaces: no local interface found for 192.168.178.61
```

After some investigation it turns out the reason for the error is that my  DNS server (an AVM fritz!box router) seems to be returning two addresses for localhost:

```
[root@rubicon postfix]# nslookup
> server 192.168.178.1
Default server: 192.168.178.1
Address: 192.168.178.1#53
> fritz.box.
Server:     192.168.178.1
Address:    192.168.178.1#53

Name:   fritz.box
Address: 192.168.178.1
> 
> 192.168.178.1
1.178.168.192.in-addr.arpa  name = fritz.box.
> 
> localhost.
Server:     192.168.178.1
Address:    192.168.178.1#53

Name:   localhost
Address: 192.168.178.61
Name:   localhost
Address: 127.0.0.1
```

I see the same results from nslookup on a Windows client.

Does anyone have any ideas what would cause that, or how to further debug the issue? I assume the fritz!box is not creating this second address by itself, but perhaps some dynamic DNS action/registration from another system on the network is causing it ... But who and why?

Suggestions? Is my theory plausible?

It doesn't seem to be the main archlinux system, journalctl shows me these log entries from dhcpd:

```
...
Dec 14 18:38:15 rubicon dhcpcd[466]: enp2s0: IAID 18:30:bc:a4
Dec 14 18:38:15 rubicon dhcpcd[466]: enp2s0: adding address fe80::661c:3ea0:2501:46ad
Dec 14 18:38:16 rubicon dhcpcd[466]: enp2s0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Dec 14 18:38:16 rubicon dhcpcd[466]: enp2s0: rebinding lease of 192.168.178.54
Dec 14 18:38:16 rubicon dhcpcd[466]: enp2s0: probing address 192.168.178.54/24
Dec 14 18:38:21 rubicon dhcpcd[466]: enp2s0: leased 192.168.178.54 for 864000 seconds
Dec 14 18:38:21 rubicon dhcpcd[466]: enp2s0: adding route to 192.168.178.0/24
Dec 14 18:38:21 rubicon dhcpcd[466]: enp2s0: adding default route via 192.168.178.1
Dec 14 18:38:21 rubicon dhcpcd[466]: forked to background, child pid 557
Dec 14 18:38:30 rubicon dhcpcd[557]: enp2s0: no IPv6 Routers available
...
```

Which all looks normal (to me) - no mention of a .61 address there.

The router is a fritz!box 7390 running version 6.83. The Linux system was just updated to 4.14.5-1-ARCH. There are a variety of other systems on the network running, for example, Windows, BSD and Android.

There doesn't seem to be (currently) a host using the .61 address e.g. pinging it fails. The linux arp cache looks like this:

```
$ ip neighbour show
192.168.178.1 dev enp2s0 lladdr 08:96:d7:78:53:6a REACHABLE
192.168.178.61 dev enp2s0  FAILED
192.168.178.250 dev enp2s0 lladdr fc:f5:28:ed:05:e5 STALE
```

(FYI: the reason Postfix was upset was that I had set the configuration option "inet_interfaces" to "localhost". Postfix was looking up this name and getting back an IP address, but not one that was configured on the local system.)

Edit: Some additional info. from the archlinux system:

```
[root@rubicon etc]# ip addr sh
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:26:18:30:bc:a4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.178.54/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::661c:3ea0:2501:46ad/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

[root@rubicon etc]# ls -ltr /etc/hosts* /etc/resolv.conf* /etc/nsswitch.conf*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 234 Feb 15  2015 /etc/nsswitch.conf_dist
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 766 Apr 11  2017 /etc/nsswitch.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  65 Oct 17 09:32 /etc/resolv.conf.pacnew
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 334 Oct 17 09:32 /etc/nsswitch.conf.pacnew
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  65 Oct 17 09:32 /etc/hosts
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  68 Dec 14 10:20 /etc/resolv.conf
```

For whatever reason the hosts file is empty (contains only comments), I don't believe I have ever had the need to edit it:

```
[root@rubicon etc]# cat hosts
# Static table lookup for hostnames.
# See hosts(5) for details.
```

resolv.conf contains:

```
# Generated by resolvconf
domain fritz.box
nameserver 192.168.178.1
```

As you can see there is a new nsswitch.conf.pacnew, apparently from a package upgrade in October. It differs only slightly from the existing nsswitch.conf, but I have moved in to replace the original. Previously I had:

```
hosts:      files dns myhostname
```

Now I have:

```
hosts: files mymachines resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns myhostname
```

Comment: `localhost` should always by resolved by looking at `/etc/hosts`, never by DNS. So have a look at your `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. To make sure the address assignment to your interfaces is correct, please edit question with output of `ip addr`.

Comment: And if the DNS service of the Fritzbox is screwed up, and some device reported it's own name as `localhost`, and the Fritzbox used this as default name: Use the Fritzbox GUI to edit the wrong `localhost` name to the correct name.

Comment: If I knew how to edit this via the GUI I would :-). That doesn't seem to be implemented. I called the AVM support number and asked them about this problem, they promised to send some debugging / log collection instructions via email, but nothing ever arrived.

Comment: What you say about localhost being resolved locally makes sense (to me). Do you have a authoritative reference for this? I presume most applications are going to do something along the lines of "gethostbyname(localhost)". So it seems that in my case, because there is no localhost entry in the hosts file, the name is being resolved via DNS to the router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an "authorative reference", but so far I've only seen systems where `/etc/hosts` contains a localhost entry.

The reasoning is that even if the network is down, local applications (which may require `localhost` lookup) can work. Also, a faulty DNS server may hijack applications which are intended to only run locally.

So: insert something like

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

in your `/etc/hosts` file.

Next, check open your Fritzbox GUI in the browser. Look at `WLAN` -> `Funknetz`, list under `Bekannte Geräte`. Is there any device named `localhost`? If yes, click the pencil (`Bearbeiten`), and change the name.

If that doesn't work, save your configuration (`System` -> `Sicherung` -> `Sichern`), remember the password, edit the file you got, look under `landevices`, and see if there's some device with `neighbour_name = "localhost"`. If yes, change the name, and restore the configuration from the Fritzbox GUI (with same password as you used when saving it).

Comment: Excellent info. on the fritzbox - Thanks! Humm, not sure how to give more detailed feedback - comment formatting seems to be limited ...

A dump from the fritzbox contains no references to the .61 address. although it is still including that address in its DNS responses. Per what I have read in the archlinux bbs forums, it seems the empty hosts file is intentional. AFAICT the intention is that localhost should be resolved via a systemd library "plugin" called "nss-myhostname". I've posted there to try and get more info.

Comment: Ah, systemd. It's entirely possible they NIH'd some different way of doing it (I don't use systemd, for this reason and others).

Comment: Indeed. Several different ways. Do you have any good pointers for replacing systemd "sub-system"?
The archlinux bug report for this issue (localhost being resolved via dns) is: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/56684
Some related systemd bug reports, for background are:
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1280 and https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1605

Comment: FYI, standards I found that might be relevant here (if RFCs are the appropriate standard for Linux/archlinux): https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6761 and https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-west-let-localhost-be-localhost-06 (draft).

Comment: Not for Archlinux. I was using Debian, and switched to Devuan (which is basically Debian, with systemd-dependencies thrown out). All systemd problems solved ...

Comment: I will follow your suggestion of adding localhost entry (entries if also for ipv6) directly in hosts. I think I will also simplify the nsswitch entry for hosts. Still don't know why my fritzbox is serving up the .61 address for localhost. I'm left with the vague feeling that there may have been some attempted hack ... :-(. Thanks again!